# Add String Attribute to CoreDataBooks

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, sqlite, core-data

I've been messing around with CoreDataBooks and trying to add another field to the sqlite file in addition to the current three.  I've added the attribute string in the .xcdatamodel, and declared it in the book.h, book.m, and localized file (all without changing the sqlite file).  However, these changes never add the field in sqlite, and the app never loads.  Each time I am deleting the app in the simulator and performing a build--> clean, but to no avail.  I've also tried changing the sqlite file to match the .xcdatamodel but the app still fails to load.

Is this a problem with CoreDataBooks or me?  Do I need to version the app before doing this?  Doesn't seem like I should have to as long as I'm deleting the app in the simulator.

Anyone know how I can add this forth string attribute (sqlite field) in CoreDataBooks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  The application WAS creating the new sqlite file, I just needed to find it within the simulator files.  Grrrr, so much time wasted when I was doing everything correctly.  Lessons learned I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found such a nice piece of code in CoreDataBooks

```
NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"CoreDataBooks.sqlite"];
/*
 Set up the store.
 For the sake of illustration, provide a pre-populated default store.
 */
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
// If the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store.
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
    NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CoreDataBooks" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    if (defaultStorePath) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
    }
}
```

in **CoreDataBooksAppDelegate.m:154**, this means for me that every time apps does not find sqlite file it is copied from bundle where it was not changed by modification of **CoreDataBooks.xcdatamodel**.

Try to use another approach, or just modify bundled sqlite file.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  So I can just change the sqlite file instead of adding the attribute through .xcdatamodel?

Comment: I've tried deleting (or renaming) the sqlite file, but the app does not recreate the sqlite file "CoreDataBooks.sqlite" with the changes like I expected.

Answer (score 1):

If the app doesn't load then there might be something wrong with your datamodel. Check the console for error messages.

And you have to decide if you want to use sqlite or core-data. If you want to monitor sqlite files for changes or add fields to sqlite files you should use sqlite and not core-data.

If you want to use core-data you should ignore the sqlite file.